# Extending router link with button action

Tags: angular

In my angular app, I have two buttons. Each button has different purpose, but navigate to same component.

So I want the buttons to achieve different actions even if they navigate to same component. How can i achieve this.

Example

without adding action.

```
this.route.navigate(['/data/test'])
path: /data/test
link: http://localhost:4200/data/test/
```

with action

```
this.route.navigate(['/data/test'])
path: /data/test
link: http://localhost:4200/data/test/button_action
```

Answer (score 1):

With [ParamMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) you can specify data for your url path, and then in your ngOnInit you can get the data to know from where you navigate.

Example [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments).